# How do I upgrade my Ionic 4 app to the latests Ionic version?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I developed an Ionic 4 app. In my package.json it says

```
"@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0"
```

Since there where several bug fixes I would like to update the app to 4.4.0

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always make sure to check the **[CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)** first to see if there're breaking changes in that version.

After that, go to the project's folder and run `npm install @ionic/angular@4.4.0 --save` to install the `4.4.0` version of Ionic Angular.

Once that finishes, you should be able to see the new version in your `package.json` file.